# Pandas create a new Probability column based on values from a function

Tags: pandas, function, dataframe, scipy

I am trying to create a new probability column using the function below. My df is a time series so the Poisson probability function needs to be calculated from index `0` to `len(df)` in that order. But I keep on getting the following errors.

```
TypeError: ("argument of type 'numpy.int32' is not iterable", 'occurred at index 0 days 11:00:00')

from scipy.stats import poisson

λ_A = 4.0
λ_B = 5.0
a = np.array([0,0,0,1,0])
b = np.array([0,0,1,1,0])
d = {'A':a, 'B':b}
Time_Interval = pd.timedelta_range('11:00:00', periods=5, freq='10T')
df = pd.DataFrame(d, Time_Interval)
```

**Here is how I attempted.**

```
def colFunc(row):
    adj_A=[]
    for index, item in enumerate(df['A']):
        if index in row['A'] == 0:
            return adj_A.append(poisson.pmf(0, λ_A*index/len(df)))
        else:
            return adj_A.append(poisson.pmf(1, λ_A*index/len(df)))
    return adj_A

df['poiss_A'] = df.apply(colFunc, axis=1)

df['poiss_B']  = df.apply(colFunc, axis=1)...with λ_B replacing λ_A.
```

**This is what I'm after.**

```
df
Out[358]: 
          Rest_A  Rest_B   poiss_A   poiss_B
11:00:00       0       0  0.449329  0.367879
11:10:00       0       0  0.201897  0.135335
11:20:00       0       1  0.090718  0.149361
11:30:00       1       1  0.130439  0.073263
11:40:00       0       0  0.018316  0.006738
```

Comment: which line triggers that error?

Comment: if index in row['A'] == 0:

Comment: row['A'] is 0 or 1, you can't ask for `x in int`

Comment: It evaluates as `(index in row['A']) == 0`,  and `row['A']` is a number not a sequence, you can't use `in` with it.

Comment: looks like you want `if row['A'] == 0`

Comment: @Yuca, if row['A'] == 0 gives all 'None' values.

Comment: row['A'] was not the right idea here. @A.Abs wanted to use the actual values of df['A'] for the first argument in poisson.pmf()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it done with `assign` but I had to get rid of the time_delta index, then add it later.

There was also an issue with your values inside poisson.pmf() you had `λ_A*index` but you need to add 1 to that because index starts at 0 in python.

```
λ_A = 4.0
λ_B = 5.0
a = np.array([0,0,0,1,0])
b = np.array([0,0,1,1,0])
d = {'A':a, 'B':b}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df = df.assign(poiss_A = poisson.pmf(df['A'], λ_A * (df['A'].index + 1) / len(df)))
df = df.assign(poiss_b = poisson.pmf(df['B'], λ_B * (df['B'].index + 1) / len(df))) 

df
Out[125]: 
   A  B   poiss_A   poiss_b
0  0  0  0.449329  0.367879
1  0  0  0.201897  0.135335
2  0  1  0.090718  0.149361
3  1  1  0.130439  0.073263
4  0  0  0.018316  0.006738

Time_Interval = pd.timedelta_range('11:00:00', periods=5, freq='10T')
df.index = Time_Interval   

df
Out[128]: 
          A  B   poiss_A   poiss_b
11:00:00  0  0  0.449329  0.367879
11:10:00  0  0  0.201897  0.135335
11:20:00  0  1  0.090718  0.149361
11:30:00  1  1  0.130439  0.073263
11:40:00  0  0  0.018316  0.006738
```